# Can someone help me switch from the Jquery Plugin Masonry to Isotope?

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

Since I am new at Jquery I am having problems switching this script over from Masonry to Isotope.  It functions exactly how I want it too while using Masonry, but when I try everything in Isotope, it doesn't animate correctly...  When I expand a .box, it just moves the other div's around and doesn't animate them but 'sliding' them to a new position.

Here is the script in Masonry format: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanjay/fgNMJ/

Hopefully someone can help...

Thanks!

Comment: If it works how you want in Masonry, why switch to Isotope?

Comment: @coreyward I can't get the filtering to work with Masonry, but I know it works with Isotope.

Comment: The animation is working for me. Are you expecting the images to slide while one is resizing? I don't believe that is possible with Isotope — look at the demos again (esp. the elements table).

Comment: @Coreyward I couldn't get Isotope to slide at all, even when the window was just resizing, even after removing the expand/collapse script.  Maybe you know how to add filtering with Masonry?  I couldn't get it to work at all.

Comment: No really, it is working for me: http://screencast.com/t/Oo0ZCEBmOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you called a wrong animated method ..

in your jsfiddle , change

```
animate: true
```

to :

```
isAnimate: true
```

and you are done ..